# Load third party js files in angular 2 component synchronously

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm trying to load some third party JavaScript files in angular 2 component.

We are using angular-cli and I tried multiple solutions where only one works, but I have other problems with that implementation.

What I tried?

**#1 To load third party JS via angular-cli.json**

```
"scripts": [
    "../assets/semantic/jquery.min.js",
    "../assets/semantic/semantic.min.js",
    "../assets/semantic/sidebar.fix.js",
    "../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js",
    "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js",

    "../assets/3dviewer/library/three.min.js",
    "../assets/3dviewer/library/trackballcontrols.js",
    "../assets/3dviewer/library/stats.min.js",
    "../assets/3dviewer/library/orbitcontrols.js",
    "../assets/3dviewer/library/projector.js",
    "../assets/3dviewer/webgl.js"
  ],
```

With that approach I'm getting js error `THREE is not defined`, but it should be because it is loaded before `trackballcontrols.js` and `orbitcontrols.js` which required three.

So it seems that angular-cli.json load third party scripts asynchronously ?

**#2 To load third party JS in component**

In component I added following piece of code

```
import   "../../../../assets/3dviewer/library/three.min.js";
import   "../../../../assets/3dviewer/library/trackballcontrols.js";
import   "../../../../assets/3dviewer/library/stats.min.js";
import   "../../../../assets/3dviewer/library/orbitcontrols.js";
import   "../../../../assets/3dviewer/library/projector.js";
import   "../../../../assets/3dviewer/webgl.js";

@Component({
    selector: "be-3d-component",
    styleUrls: ["./3d.component.css"],
    templateUrl: "./3d.component.html",
})
```

In that case I'm also getting the same error as it is in first step

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:3146:2)
    at j (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:26:8), <anonymous>:2:29568)
    at k (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:26:8), <anonymous>:2:29882)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:148424:35)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:148300:47)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:148494:33)
    at data.args.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:149373:25)
```

**#3 Loading third party trough index.html**

```
<script src="/assets/3dviewer/library/three.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/3dviewer/library/trackballcontrols.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/3dviewer/library/stats.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/3dviewer/library/orbitcontrols.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/3dviewer/library/projector.js" type="text/javascript"  ></script>
  <script src="/assets/3dviewer/webgl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In this case everything works.

But that is not what I want. As you can see my third party js code is related to 3d viewer, and we are having memory leaking somewhere in above files. Currently we don't have resources and enough time to find what is the reason so we are looking for workaround.

Win-win will be if we can load above files only when 3d component is opened and after we navigate somewhere else in app to throw away those files so browser memory will be released.

Any hints, suggestions will be very ,very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If the the problem is Three, the question should address it directly. It can't be extrapolated to all third party JS files. Because for some random file that has support for modules it is just `import`.

Answer (score 0):

in component you can use ->

```
var SystemJS = require('systemjs');

// loads './app.js' from the current directory
SystemJS.import('./app.js').then(function(m) {
  console.log('library loaded',m);
});
```

also you will get callback when library loaded